# Can access from IP but not from domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain

I can access a site from an IP but can't access from a particular domain name. I have other domain names pointing to the same server and they all working. This server is a Windows web server 2008.

What could the problem be?  What steps should I take to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is the DNS for the domain set up to point at the IP address with an A record?

Comment: http://www.intodns.com/spotagel.com and http://www.intodns.com/spotagel-emlak.com giving different results but both of them same dns and yes it points the ip address with A record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content DNS server at 188.138.56.201 is misconfigured:

```
[M:\]dnsqry /serverip:188.138.56.201 a spotagel.com.
[0.0.0.0:0000] -> [188.138.56.201:0035] 30
Header: 0000 1+0+0+0, Q, , query, no_error
Question: spotagel.com. IN A

[188.138.56.201:0035] -> [0.0.0.0:0000] 30
Header: 0000 1+0+0+0, R, , query, refused
Question: spotagel.com. IN A

[M:\]dnsqry /serverip:188.138.56.201 a spotagel-emlak.com.
[0.0.0.0:0000] -> [188.138.56.201:0035] 36
Header: 0000 1+0+0+0, Q, , query, no_error
Question: spotagel-emlak.com. IN A

[188.138.56.201:0035] -> [0.0.0.0:0000] 97
Header: 0000 1+1+2+0, R, AUTH, query, no_error
Question: spotagel-emlak.com. IN A
Answer: spotagel-emlak.com. IN A 86400 188.138.56.201
Authority: spotagel-emlak.com. IN NS 86400 ns1.spotagel.com.
Authority: spotagel-emlak.com. IN NS 86400 ns2.spotagel.com.

[M:\]
```

There are various well-known causes for such an error, for different content DNS server softwares.  For Microsoft's DNS server, for example, this can be caused by a DNS content server configured to be a secondary server for the "zone" having a problem replicating its database.  For ISC's BIND, for example, one would look to "views" as a potential cause of this.

Comment: this is a windows web server and i cant find DNS configuration, where shold i do configuration

Comment: That depends from what your DNS server is.  The rest of us aren't clairvoyant.  **You** have to provide **us** with the information about what your software is.  You don't even tell us what revision of Windows Web Server 2008 you have.  For prior to R2, you'd have had to install your own DNS server software, since Microsoft didn't supply any in the box.  Again, our lack of clairvoyance means that we cannot tell what that software would have been.

Comment: If DNS is misconfigured, you need to know who manages DNS for the domain in question. It sounds like this is not yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a DNS issue. Ensure that you can resolve the FQDN in question to the correct IP address. Also, if there is a proxy server involved, make sure it can resolve the name. If you have recently setup the DNS mapping, then it may take some time to propagate to other servers. Start by using nslookup on the client machine to lookup the machine name.

Also, check the configuration of the web server to ensure it will accept connections with that name - typically the default is to accept all IPs and all names (host headers), but they can be configured differently.

Comment: before 27 May it was working expected, but suddenly it couldn't server. http://www.spotagel.com not working but http://www.spotagel-emlak.com working strange

Comment: when nslookup saying dns not found fro spotagel.com but it finds for spotagel-emlak.com both of them have same dns  ns1.spotagel.com, please help